# How to convert date string into date format in js

Tags: javascript

**Note:   START_DATE & END_DATE in String Format, String Format is :"29-06-2018 14:11"**

### I want to convert START_DATE & END_DATE into Date Format.

```
 function checkConstraints2() {
        debugger
        var currentyear = document.getElementById('START_DATE').value;
        var builtYear = document.getElementById('END_DATE').value;
        var dif = currentyear < builtYear
        if (dif) {
            document.getElementById("validationBuiltyaer2").style.display = "none";
            return true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("validationBuiltyaer2").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("validationBuiltyaer2").innerText = "End Date Should be Greater Than From Date";
            flag = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use `momentjs`

Comment: we want to check this condition  currentyear < builtYear.  It is string so its only comparing day, its not comparing month & year. so we want to convert its in Date Format.

Comment: then you can use only year by *"YYYY"* to parse date

Comment: Why is this question tagged C# and Oracle? If the immediate question is purely JavaScript then please remove those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can use `moment` to parse date string -

```js
var dateString = "29-06-2018 14:11";

console.log(moment(dateString, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"));

var startDateString = "29-06-2018 14:11";
var endDateString = "30-06-2018 14:11";

var startDate = moment(startDateString, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
var endDate = moment(endDateString, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");

console.log(startDate < endDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var parts = '29-06-2018 14:11'.split(' ')[0].split('-');
// Please substract 1 from month part as javaScript counts months from 0:
// January - 0, February - 1, etc.
var mydate = new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
```